# Как в Java рекурсивно удалить из списка детей, чьи предки уже есть в этом же списке

Tags: java, коллекции

Есть `ArrayList` с объектами, скажем, `Item`. У каждого объекта есть поле `Long id`, `Long parentId` и `List subitems`, где лежат такие же объекты `Item`, либо же там пусто. Необходимо пройтись по списку, найти такие `Item`, которые являются subitem-ами какого-либо `Item`, который уже представлен в том же списке, и такие subitem-ы удалить.

Неприятное ограничение - Java 7 + Guava, так как стримы на Android не завезли.

Comment: Item-ы сраниваются на равенство по ссылке, по `id` или через `equals`?

Comment: А в чем сложность? Создаем коллекцию хранящую итемы. Рекурсивно обходим дерево проверяя нет ли в коллекции этого итема. Если нет, то добавляем и идем дальше, если есть - удаляем.

Comment: @Nofate по `id`.

Comment: @GreyGoblin сложность сделать это красиво и шустро.

Comment: @Bringoff при той структуре, что вы описали, если больше нет никаких условий по которому можно ограничить поиск существующих объектов  быстрее чем O(n) не получится. То есть обычный линейный обход. А красивость реализуется рекурсией.

Comment: Да, `HashSet` для хранения найденных Item-ов и отброса дубликатов и рекурсивный обход. Только сравнение по `id` нужно будет в `equals` унести и переопределить `hashCode()`.

Comment: @Nofate то, к чему додумал сам, написал в ответ. Возможно, будут какие-то мысли.

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент пришел к такому решению, но не уверен, что оно оптимальное

```
 /**
 * Checks if subitem's ancestor is presented in the same list and if so removes that subitem from list
 *
 * @param items list to search in (subitems must be updated {@see updateSubItems})
 * @return new list with redundant subitems removed.
 */
public List<Item> removeSubItemsIfParentPresented(List<Item> items) {
    List<Item> result = new ArrayList<>(items);

    // iterate items, but pass and modify result
    for (Item item : items) {
        clearListFromRedundantSubitemsRecursively(result, item.getSubItems());
    }

    return result;
}

/**
 * This method modifies input list, be careful.
 *
 * @param listToClear
 * @param subitemsToSearch
 */
private void clearListFromRedundantSubitemsRecursively(List<Item> listToClear, List<Item> subitemsToSearch) {
    Iterator<Item> iterator = listToClear.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Item current = iterator.next();

        for (Item subitem : subitemsToSearch) {
            if (!subitem.getSubItems().isEmpty()) {
                clearListFromRedundantSubitemsRecursively(listToClear, subitem.getSubItems());
            }
            if (subitem.getId() == current.getId()) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```